# how does delivery failure affect JMS message ordering

Tags: jms, weblogic, messaging

I am using weblogic 11g but this question applies to JMS messaging in general.
Lets assume i have messages in queue in the order 5-4-3-2-1 
If message#1 fails to deliver and there is a re-delivery delay of 30 secs on the JMS queue. Will the messages behind 1 get delivered during those 30 secs or will they also have to wait for 30 secs on this case ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer .. leaving reference for future.

Following article 
*http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6334*

lists the following in **Poison Messages** section - 
"Note that messages with a redelivery delay do not prevent other messages from being delivered"